# Is it a good idea to use connect() on many small reusable reactjs components in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Suppose I have a small reusable component called `<LikePanel>` which will be used across multiple pages in different types of parent components, like `<BlogEntry>` or `<ItemEntry>` or `<ReplyEntry>`.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {likeAction} from './LikeAction'


class LikePanel extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return <ButtonGroup className={this.props.className}>
            <Button onClick={()=>this.onClickLiking()}>
                <Glyphicon glyph="thumbs-up"/>{this.props.like}</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>

    }

    onClickLiking(type){
       this.props.dispatch(likeAction());
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   let obj = {};
   obj[LIKE] = state[LIKE];
   return obj;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LikePanel)
```

Example use cases of `LikePanel`:

```
class BlogEntry extends React.Component{

    render(){

       return this.props.data.entry.map((item)=>{

           return <div>
                       {item.article}
                       <LikePanel like={item.like}/>
                  </div> 
       }
    }
}


class ProductEntry extends React.Component{

    render(){

       return this.props.data.entry.map((item)=>{

           return <div>
                       <ProductPanel data={item}/>
                       <LikePanel like={item.like}/>
                  </div> 
       }
    }
}
```

So if a webpage has 20 blog entries there will be 20 connected `<LikePanel>` on the page, and there is a possibility in the future that extra components will be connected to redux. Is it a good practice to use `connect()` with such a small components like `<LikePanel>`?

Comment: You might consider gathering the values needed for each smaller component in a `connect` on the parent, and then passing them through to each child directly as a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's absolutely fine.  Use `connect` wherever it makes sense in your component hierarchy.  One common pattern is to have a list component be connected and use `mapState` to retrieve the IDs of the data items in the list, render some `<ListItem id={itemId} />` child component for each item, and have each child component also be connected and look up its own data by ID.  Also see the Redux FAQ question at https://redux.js.org/faq/react-redux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree .

Comment: link is now: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components

Comment: Yep, I split up the FAQ page a while back.  Updated my answer - thanks!

Comment: Twitter has released web mobile version a few months ago. I have been inspecting the code just for fun using react dev tools. I noticed they connect every tweet in the list. Every tweet has a bottom "share" bar which is also connected to the store. Step-by-step: https://medium.com/statuscode/dissecting-twitters-redux-store-d7280b62c6b1